# How to dynamically route an incoming request by using a URL->responsible-backend-service mapping service?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am new to spring-cloud-gateway and I can't answer the question if I solved my problem the intended way. I hope someone can point me into the right direction, give advice or provide some exemplary sample code.

Requirement:
An incoming request at my spring-cloud-gateway service shall be forwarded to the correct backend service (there are X of such backend services, each responsible for a specific task).
The request itself does not contain enough information to decide which backend service to route to.

An additional REST-service exists that maps an arbitrary URL-to-responsible-backend-service-name. The response format is some small JSON, containing the name of the backend-service to forward to.

What would be the easiest/best/smartest/intended solution to implement this functionality with spring-cloud-gateway?

I tried implementing a `GatewayFilter` that first calls the mapping-service and depending on the result set `GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR`for the exchange.
This works ok. But I have additional questions.

1. Is it possible to omit the `.uri("not://needed"))` part in the route setup?
2. Why does the order value need to be higher than 9999? (see code example)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator myRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes().route(r -> r
                .alwaysTrue()
                .filters(f -> f.filter(new CustomRequestFilter()))
                .uri("not://needed"))  // how to omit ?
                .build();
    }


    public static class CustomRequestFilter implements GatewayFilter, Ordered {

        @Override
        public int getOrder() {
            return 10000; // why order > 9999 ?  (below 10000 does not work)
        }

        @Override
        public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {

            return getBackendServiceMappingResult(exchange.getRequest().getURI().toString()) //async call to REST service mapping URL->backend service name
                    .flatMap(mappingResult -> {
                        URI uri = mapServiceNameToBackendService(mappingResult.getServiceName());
                        exchange.getAttributes().put(ServerWebExchangeUtils.GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR, uri);
                        return chain.filter(exchange);
                    });
        }

        private URI mapServiceNameToBackendService(String serviceName) {
            try {
                switch (serviceName) {
                    case "serviceA": return new URI("http://httpbin.org:80/get");
                    case "serviceB": return new URI("https://someotherhost:443/");
                }
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                //ignore
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    static class MappingResult {
        String serviceName;
        public String getServiceName() {
            return serviceName;
        }
    }

    static Mono<MappingResult> getBackendServiceMappingResult(String uri) {
        WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080");
        return client.get().uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/mapping").queryParam("uri", uri).build()).retrieve().bodyToMono(MappingResult.class);
    }
}
```

Is there a better approach (with spring-cloud-gateway) to solve the requirement?

Comment: URI is required. I usually go with `no://op` as it is short. Ordering matters because there are other filters that might affect the outcome.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @spencergibb. Can you provide more information on the chain of filters? I just set up one single filter, that should kick in first, no matter what the ordering is. If I set order to Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE or Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - bot yield to the same wrong result. The response is just an empty body 200er instead of the response of the requested service. I don't really understand this behavior.

Comment: Additionally I would love to know, if the implementation in general is coherent with what the main contributors of spring-cloud-gateway had in mind. Had they solved the requirement in a different way?

Comment: I wrote most of gateway. It looks fine to me.

Comment: I have a use case similar to this, however I need to make two non blocking calls, the second after the first, would splitting it into different filters be a best practice ?

Comment: You can solve your problem using below  code                                                                                @Bean
    public RouteLocator myRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes().route(r ->
                r.alwaysTrue()
                .filters(f-> {
                    f.changeRequestUri(serverWebExchange -> buildRequestUri(serverWebExchange,new CustomRequestFilter()));
                    return f;
                })
                .uri(env.getProperty("birdeye.platform.url")))
                .build();

Answer (score -1):

You can use this

```
 @Bean
public RouteLocator myRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes().route(r ->
            r.alwaysTrue()
            .filters(f-> {
                f.changeRequestUri(serverWebExchange -> buildRequestUri(serverWebExchange, CustomRequestFilter));
                return f;
            })
            .uri(env.getProperty("birdeye.platform.url")))
            .build();
```

private Optional buildRequestUri(ServerWebExchange exchange,CustomRequestFilter customRequestFilter ){

```
    boolean updateuri = true;
    if(updateuri) {
        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
        String path = request.getPath().pathWithinApplication().value();
        
        try {
             uriBiulder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(new URI(backendUri)).path(backendPath)
    
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else {
        uriBiulder = new URI("https://paytm.com:8080/category/create") 
    }
    return Optional.of(uriBiulder);
    
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).